# Jacobian of the transformation from y to z

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I'm stuck in this problem where I'm asked to verify that the Jacobian of the transformation from y to z (where z=ay+b) is

[image]

what's the transformation from y to z in this case? is it y=z/a+b/a ?
relation 1.10 is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you have it correct. $z=ay+b$ so $y=z/a+b/a$. The Jacobian in 1 dimension is just the $1 \times 1$ scalar matrix $[y'(z)]$ which has determinant  $y'(z)$, so $J_y(z) = y'(z)=1/a$.
Thus the change of variables formula tells us we need to multiply by $|J_y(z)| = |a^{-1}|$.

Since this is a 1D problem, you would probably be more familiar with calling it a $u$-substitution, i.e. $u=ay+b$ so $du = ady$ or $dy/du = 1/a$.